# Integrating Wolfram Alpha API in Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, wolframalpha

I have an appID for the WolframAlpha short answer API but do not know how to integrate the query requests into the Dialogflow program. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level you would integrate using the **Dialogflow Fulfillment** feature to pass information from your user to code either in a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) or to a webhook.

Once the information is there then your code in a Cloud Function or on another system that can accept webhooks will need to send the info it received from Dialogflow over to WolframAlpha's short answer API to get a reply and to process that reply into the format needed for Dialogflow.  Dialogflow will then take the response (if it was returned quickly enough) and return it to your user.